# Move item from list to another one for poker card game Python

Tags: python

I'm trying to make poker game in Python. In the while fuction I want to move the used cards in a separate(used cards) list. The problem is sometimes when I print the hand I can get duplicates. Something is wrong with my sorting strategy and I don't know what. Can you help me?

```
import random

deck = ['AS', 'KS', 'QS', 'JS', '10S', '9S', '8S', '7S', '6S', '5S', '4S', '3S', '2S',\
         'AD', 'KD', 'QD', 'JD', '10D', '9D', '8D', '7D', '6D', '5D', '4D', '3D', '2D',\
         'AC', 'KC', 'QC', 'JC', '10C', '9C', '8C', '7C', '6C', '5C', '4C', '3C', '2C',\
         'AH', 'KH', 'QH', 'JH', '10H', '9H', '8H', '7H', '6H', '5H', '4H', '3H', '2H']

used = []
p1 = []
p2 = []
a = 0

while (a < 2):
    drawn_card = random.choice(deck)
    deck.append(drawn_card)
    deck = [f for f in deck if f not in used]
    p1.append(drawn_card)
    a+=1
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well the random choice is not guaranteed to be **unique**, thus when you do:

```
drawn_card = random.choice(deck)
..
p1.append(drawn_card)
```

you may end up having duplicates (that explains that you some time see duplicates and some not).

Check if `drawn_card` is **in the list** first and if not, then append. That way you won't have duplicates. In code you could it like this:

```
if drawn_card not in p1:
    p1.append(drawn_card)
```

---

Or, as Rory Daulton said:

If you are allowed, you could shuffle the entire deck, then remove consecutive items from that list.

Comment: @gsamaras Great!! This fixed my problem :)

Comment: Yes, that's better, though you did not need to include my name. You get my upvote, anyway.

Answer (score 0):

you need to compare the random card with "p1" not with "deck":

```
import random

deck = ['AS', 'KS', 'QS', 'JS', '10S', '9S', '8S', '7S', '6S', '5S', '4S', '3S', '2S',\
         'AD', 'KD', 'QD', 'JD', '10D', '9D', '8D', '7D', '6D', '5D', '4D', '3D', '2D',\
         'AC', 'KC', 'QC', 'JC', '10C', '9C', '8C', '7C', '6C', '5C', '4C', '3C', '2C',\
         'AH', 'KH', 'QH', 'JH', '10H', '9H', '8H', '7H', '6H', '5H', '4H', '3H', '2H']

used = []
p1 = []
a = 0

while (a < 2):
    drawn_card = random.choice(deck)
    print(drawn_card)
    if drawn_card not in p1:
        p1.append(drawn_card)
        a += 1
        continue
print (p1)
```